# Powershell script won't list expired key vault certificates

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I have a powershell script that is attempting to list all the expired secrets of my Azure Key Vault. Unfortunately I'm struggling to do this.

This is how I retrieve sercrets. But what do I need to add to get the expiration of all secrets? Then delete those that are expired? I'm guessing I'll need to set an access policy.

```
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription "My subscriptsion"
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "testKeyVaultPwsh" -UserPrincipalName "mystuff@domain.com" -PermissionsToSecrets get,set,delete

#Retrieve secret
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "testKeyVaultPwsh" -Name "ExamplePassword" -AsPlainText
```

Comment: Each secret returned by `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` has an `Expires` property, check that: `$secret |Select-Object Id,Expires`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can delete the expired secrets using below commands .(*Make sure
  you have get,set,delete access policies set and given proper
  permissions* )

***I have tried in my environment and able to delete expired secrets sussessfully.***

After checking expiry using

```
$exp =Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultname -Name $secretname | Select-Object Name,Expires
$exp
```

- I created secrets and have secrets expired.

[image]

**Commands:**

```
$vaultname= “<keyvaultname>”
$secrets= Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultname
$secretnames =$secrets.Name
$current_date=Get-Date
Foreach($secretname in $secretnames)
{
$exp =Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultname -Name $secretname | Select-Object Expires
$keyvaultsecretvexpirydate =[datetime]($exp.Expires)

             $timediff=NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $current_date -End $keyvaultsecretvexpirydate
             $days_until_expiration=$timediff.Days
Write-Output “days_until_expiration  of secret named $secretname is  :$days_until_expiration”
Write-Output “ ”

if ($days_until_expiration -eq 0) 
{
    Write-Output  "Secret named $secretname got expired “
Write-Output  “removing expired secret : $secretname”
Write-Output  “ ”
Remove-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultname -Name $secretname
}

}
```

[image]

***Confirm to delete by typing **Y** and refresh the secrets page to see the expired secret being removed/deleted.***

[image]

**References:**

1. [KeyVaultSecretExpirationAlerts |github](https://github.com/sagu94271/seaa/blob/main/Devops/Powershell/KeyVaultSecretExpirationAlerts.ps1)
2. [remove-azkeyvaultsecret | microsoftdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/remove-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-8.2.0)